# Based on cell formula, display another cell value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet

I want Excel to look into the formula of a cell and then display a different cell based on that. confused yet?

Column A on sheet 1 has a size and column B on sheet 1 has a tolerance.

Could be same numbers in both column throughout. Now on sheet 2 I want to be able in column A to reference, lets say A4/1 with a simple `=sheet1!A4` that I can manually put in and then I want column B on sheet 2 to display B4 from sheet 1.

Is there a formula I can put into sheet 2 cell B4 to make this happen? Does it make a difference if I reference A4/1 and I want B4/2 to display C4/1?

I'm looking to create a relationships between the 2 cells essentially. I hope it was clear enough to understand.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why would you ever need it, but this is my answer how I would access the contents of the formula and get another value based on that.

Sheet1:
[image]

In `Sheet2!A2` there is the formula `=Sheet1!A4`
In `Sheet2!B2` there is the formula `=OFFSET(INDIRECT(MID(FORMULATEXT(A2),2,999)),0,1)`

[image: Using that formula you access]

`FORMULATEXT` returns the formula in text format (`=Sheet1!A4`).
`MID` part removes the `=` from the beginning (`Sheet1!A4`).
`INDIRECT` makes `Sheet1!A4` a valid reference instead of just text.
`OFFSET` gets the value from 1 cell to the right (`Sheet1!B4`).

Comment: If the answer helped to solve the problem please check the ✓ symbol next to the answer.